# Placing methods to retrieve data related to a class in a separate class or not

Tags: c#, java, oop, coding-style

Consider the following, simplified class:

```
class Book {
   string title;
   Author author;
}
```

Simple enough. However, when adding methods like `getBookFromDatabase(int bookId)`, should this be placed as a `static` **method in this same** class, **or** rather in a **separate** (i.e) `BookManager`-**class**?

Usage example:

```
Book b = Book.getBookFromDatabase(42);
```

vs.

```
Book b = BookManager.getBookFromDatabase(42);
```

I do realize that this is somewhat a matter of taste, but what is the optimal following the OOP-guidlines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I like the "`Manager`" class approach. It separates the logic, so that a `Book` doesn't have to know anything about how to acquire itself.  Also, `BookManager` can be a singleton here - not instantiated until one actually needs to acquire a `Book`.

Furthermore, the `BookManager` can perform additionaly book-keeping tasks *(no pun intended)*, such as caching, or maybe there are some `Book` events to subscribe to at a global level.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use a `Repository` to rehydrate objects from a backing store.  Something like the following might be a good starting point.

```
public interface IBookRepository{
    Book Load(int id);
    void Save(Book book);
}
```

This way you can have multiple different implementations of a repository and not necessarily be tied to using a database.  For example you might have an `InMemoryBookRepository` that you can use for testing and a `DatabaseBookRepository` for a production like environment.

Stylistically I would also avoid using static methods like:

```
BookManager.getBookFromDatabase(42);
```

It's harder to test and the resultant code is more tightly coupled together which will make testing and change much harder.

You can take a look at this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175/repository-pattern-tutorial-in-c-sharp) for where to learn more about implementing a repository.  [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) and [Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) also describe it in much more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be better to use separate class. This may be BookManager but maybe there is something better suitable for the job like Library or BookShop. The object should hold references to books in array or ArrayList (I would advise to use ArrayList) like this:

```
public class BookManager {
    ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();

    public Book getBook(int index) {
        return books.get(index);
    }

    public void addBook(Book book) {
        books.add(book);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If all your `Book` class' behavior is in storing fields retrieved from the database, then it might be simpler for you to just add the behavior of getting the data from the database, i.e. `getBookFromDatabase(int bookId)` on the same class, since all of the class would be concerned with retrieving a book from the database and presenting it cohesively to the rest of the program.

However, if you intend for your `Book` class to have additional behavior, perhaps certain Book business logic specific to your application, then perhaps it might make more sense to have *business logic* kept separate from *persistence logic*.

The guiding heuristic here should be the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), there are [plenty of other questions on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=single+responsibility+principle) about it.

Also bear in mind, on a separate but related note, that [static methods are death to testability](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/12/15/static-methods-are-death-to-testability/).

Answer (score 0):

Both of your approaches use static methods which are inherently non-OOP. The best solution would be to have a `BookDatabase` object and this object should grant non-static access to books it contains.

This will solve the issues that static methods bring. For example, what if you have two or more BookDatabases in the future? With static methods, this gets messy. With Database objects, you simply have more instances of this class (or subclasses) to handle different databases.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your Book class is a domain/Business class, therefore placing the responsibity of retrieving data to it from your database on the class itself, you are creating high coupling between your database and your business layer, which is against the principles of good design.

I will recommend that you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)

And if you're up for it get a copy of

Applying UML and Patterns: An Introduction to Object-Oriented Analysis and Design and Iterative Development - By Craig Larman
ISBN13:  978-0131489066

This book is one of the most popular books on software development and comes highly recommended.